# Url.Action passing List object to controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
@{
    string guid = null;
    List<GalleryItemsViewModel> galleryItemsViewModel = new List<GalleryItemsViewModel>();
    foreach (var item in Model.ListingGalleryItems.Where(x => x.IsFloorplan))
    {
        galleryItemsViewModel.Add(new GalleryItemsViewModel
        {
            FileGuid = item.FileGuid
        });

    }

    <div>galleryitems @galleryItemsViewModel.Count()</div>

    <a class="accent" href='@Url.Action("Download", "File", new { galleryItemsModel = galleryItemsViewModel, ID = Model.ID, fileGuid = guid, returnUrl = this.Request.RawUrl }, null)'>
        <img src='@Url.Content("~/images/optimisedImages/property-info/floorplan.png")' />
        Floorplan
    </a>
}

public ActionResult Download(List<GalleryItemsViewModel> galleryItemsModel, string fileGuid, int id, string returnUrl)
{
  //stuff
}
```

I'm trying to pass a list of GUID's to my controller for download, the items are being added to the list & returns a count of 2
However, the galleryItemsModel object is null when I hit the controller breakpoint.

Comment: Did you look at the page's HTML source to verify that the link being generated is correct? It may give you some insights

Comment: No I hadn't - good suggestion!

Comment: <a class="accent" href='/File/Download/285?galleryItemsModel=System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BAirListing.Models.ViewModels.GalleryItemsViewModel%5D&amp;returnUrl=%2FListing%3FlistingId%3D285'>
                <img src='/images/optimisedImages/property-info/floorplan.png' />
                Floorplan
            </a>
This is what I got

Comment: Why in the world would you want to send back to the controller what the controller just sent to the view (pointless extra overhead that is just degrading performance)

Answer (score 0):

```html
        @{
            string guid = null;
            string guidList = "";
            foreach (var item in Model.ListingGalleryItems.Where(x => x.IsFloorplan))
            {
                guidList += item.FileGuid + ",";
            }

            <a class="accent" href='@Url.Action("Download", "File", new { fileGuidList = guidList, ID = Model.ID, fileGuid = guid, returnUrl = this.Request.RawUrl }, null)'>
                <img src='@Url.Content("~/images/optimisedImages/property-info/floorplan.png")' />
                Floorplan
            </a>
        }
```

```html
public ActionResult Download(string fileGuidList, string fileGuid, int id, string returnUrl)
{
    string[] items = fileGuidList.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

      foreach(var item in items)
      {
          fileGuid = item;
      }
}
```

Passed as a list of strings!